# SQL Server behave differently to stop Execution in different types of error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have list of `Alter Table` statements:

```
BEGIN

    ALTER TABLE TABLE1 ALTER COLUMN AA INT -- Error Here
    ALTER TABLE TABLE1 ALTER COLUMN BB INT
    PRINT('CONTINUE AFTER ERROR')

END
```

After error its stopped execution and skipped other statements.

In output it shows only 1 error.

But in 2nd case where i have a list of DROP INDEX Statements

```
BEGIN
    DROP INDEX TABLE1.INDEX1  -- Error Here
    DROP INDEX TABLE2.INDEX2
    PRINT('CONTINUE AFTER ERROR')
END
```

Here after error, it continues execution and prints error log and the text 'CONTINUE AFTER ERROR'.

Why this difference ?

Comment: Because error-handling in tsql has generally been inconsistently implemented as [noted by Erland](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html)

Answer (score 1):

The difference in behavior is because the first batch of `ALTER TABLE` statements is a compilation error whereas the second batch of `DROP INDEX` statements is a runtime error.

When a compilation error occurs on a batch, no code executes and only the compilation error is returned. Also, since no code executes with a compilation error, the error cannot even be caught with structured error handling:

```
BEGIN TRY
        ALTER TABLE TABLE1 ALTER COLUMN AA INT -- Error Here
        ALTER TABLE TABLE1 ALTER COLUMN BB INT
        PRINT('CONTINUE AFTER ERROR')
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'CAUGHT ERROR';
END CATCH;
```

> Msg 4902, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Cannot find the object "TABLE1"
> because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

When compilation is successful and a runtime error happens, subsequent statements in the same batch may or may not execute after an error depending the error severity and `XACT_ABORT setting`.

Comment: Add a note about `XACT_ABORT`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because the ALTER TABLE statements actually touch the data in the given tables. Removing the index does not have that impact, so I guess SQL decides it is OK to continue with the next statement.